# Bootstrap/bootflat and jQuery progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get a progress bar to display and animate while I am loading an html page into a div with jQuery.

My progress bar comes from bootstrap (bootflat) and looks like this:

```
<div class="progress" style="visibility:hidden;">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">60%</div>
</div>
```

My script looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnTicker").click(function(){
        var ticker = this.form.txtTicker.value;
        $("#progress-bar").show();
        $("#info").load('info.php?t=' + ticker, function() {
            success: $("#progress-bar").hide();
            } );        
    });
});
```

I just can't figure how to get the progress bar displayed and moving; just need a bit of guidance as I did a google search and couldn't find any tutorials for beginners (which is what I am).

Thanks

Comment: Not sure here, can you create a fiddle?

Comment: You can see the code in action here: http://stocks.listfield.com

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#progress-bar").show();
```

should be

```
$("#progress-bar").css('visibility', 'visible');
```

The `show()` method doesn't deal with visibility.